# NextJS 14, MUI 5.15, server error `Internal error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '300')`

Tags: next.js, material-ui

Following the instructions at https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/nextjs/ and https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/, I am trying to add MUI to an existing NextJS site. I have added the packages, and am getting the following error in the console:

```bash
⨯ Internal error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '300')
    at ButtonRoot.ownerState.ownerState (./node_modules/@mui/material/Button/Button.js:116:96)
    at muiStyledFunctionResolver (./node_modules/@mui/system/esm/createStyled.js:127:28)
    at transformedStyleArg (./node_modules/@mui/system/esm/createStyled.js:245:48)
    at handleInterpolation (./node_modules/@emotion/serialize/dist/emotion-serialize.browser.esm.js:127:34)
    at serializeStyles (./node_modules/@emotion/serialize/dist/emotion-serialize.browser.esm.js:230:19)
    at eval (./node_modules/@emotion/styled/base/dist/emotion-styled-base.worker.esm.js:120:97)
    at eval (./node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-2408c5fb.worker.esm.js:75:24)
    at renderWithHooks (./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.development.js:8245:26)
    at renderIndeterminateComponent (./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.development.js:8307:25)
    at renderElement (./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.development.js:8528:21)
```

The page's content is:

```js
"use client"

import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

import '@fontsource/roboto/300.css';

export default function Page() {

    return (
        <>
            <p>Hi!</p>

            <Button variant="contained">Do something fun.</Button>
        </>
    )
}
```

```js
// layout.tsx
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import './globals.css'

import { AppRouterCacheProvider } from '@mui/material-nextjs/v14-appRouter'

export const runtime = 'edge'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'St Albert Nordic Trail Report',
  description: 'St Albert Nordic Trail Grooming Report',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <AppRouterCacheProvider>
          <div className="container">
            {children}
            <hr />
            <ul>
              <li><Link href="/">Home</Link></li>
              <li><Link href="/admin/">Admin</Link></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </AppRouterCacheProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

```js
// package.json
{
  "name": "trail-nextjs",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^5.0.8",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.2",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.2",
    "@mui/material-nextjs": "^5.15.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "@tanstack/react-table": "^8.11.2",
    "@tanstack/solid-table": "^8.10.7",
    "@tanstack/svelte-table": "^8.10.7",
    "@tanstack/table-core": "^8.10.7",
    "@tanstack/vue-table": "^8.10.7",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "immer": "^10.0.3",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lucide-react": "^0.292.0",
    "next": "14.0.3",
    "next-intl": "^3.1.3",
    "react": "^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.24.0",
    "react-datetime-picker": "^5.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0",
    "react-leaflet": "^4.2.1",
    "sass": "^1.69.5",
    "swr": "^2.2.4",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.0.0",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "use-immer": "^0.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@cloudflare/next-on-pages": "^1.8.0",
    "@cloudflare/workers-types": "^4.20231121.0",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.8",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.3",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5",
    "wrangler": "^3.17.1"
  }
}
```

I'd like to describe what I've tried, but I can't - I don't understand where the error is coming from, and as best as I can tell, I've followed the installation procedure to add MUI to the project.

Comment: At this point, your page component is fine to render with SSR until add an event. Please, update your question with the `layout.tsx` file and `package.json` file.

Comment: Layout and package file content added.  Through flipping switches, it seems to be a problem with `export const runtime = 'edge'`.

Comment: yes, this @emotion style system error comes from edge runtime. There is a PR for it, https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/39229